# Computer sound/audio not working since switched to Vista

Tags: windows-vista, audio, drivers

I got Vista for my HP laptop Pavilion DV1000.  Before it had Windows XP and Linux but the laptop says "Vista Capable".  My computer's sound worked before.  Since getting Windows Vista roughly a year ago, among other problems, my computer has had NO sound.

> No Audio Output Device Is Installed

… is the message I see when I hover over the sound icon at the bottom of the screen.  Device Manager → High Definition Audio Device has an exclamation point over the icon.  When I click it it says:

> This device cannot start. (Code 10)

When I click "Check for solutions" a message says "Could not load driver software".  It says Windows is checking for solutions to the problem. Then the message box disappears and I still have no sound.

Is this something that can be fixed easily?  Would it be better to send it to repair?

Comment: There's always a way to tell a problem without ranting. People don't really want to see that here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be the HD Audio Driver.  I have found it a challenge to find for some systems but a search will find it  [HP RealTek HD Audio](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&softwareitem=PSG_I23778-109040)  Also look for any chipset driver packages for theIntel chipset

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem with Realtek sound. simply go to Control Panel, switch to Classic View, and open the Device Manager. Then open the Sound folder, click on the Realtek and DISABLE it, then ENABLE it again, problem should get solved.

Or else try to re-install your audio driver, I suggest you to install the latest audio driver for vista.